# Draw a line on top of entire layout in Android?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am drag and dropping an ImageView on to another ImageView.

I am following this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

While I can display a drag shadow and change drop targets with different colors and drawables. I am happy with the article.

But I am looking for a little bit more. I am looking to draw a straight line between my drag shadow and the source. I want this line to be straight and update it's length and direction as I drag the item around. When I finally drop the item in my drop zone I want the line to stay permanently (unless I remove it later).

Like this:
[image: Drag without line, this is my current situation]
Drag without line, this is my current situation
[image: Drag with a line following, this is what I want]
Drag with a line following, this is what I want

I should also mention that I want to do this with multiple sources and single target (maybe multiple target in future).

Here is the code that I am working on https://github.com/ishanatmuz/HelloDrag

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to override onDraw( Canvas ) and then when you are dragging call a routine to draw your line.

When you are not dragging draw the lines between the boxes.

both routines as sub-routines of onDraw

If you do this don't forget to call super.onDraw( Canvas ).

Comment: Which View's onDraw(Canvas) should I override? Where to make those sub-routines? .... I am not asking you to do the whole thing for me. Just a little more guidance. A basic structure of what goes where will be very helpful.

Comment: I don't have your code, but I'm assuming you would want to do it on your drop target. Take a look at how people extends SurfaceView to do drawing. You can do similar, but simple stuff in any View class. Hope this helps a little.